# Android Auto not working with Samsung Galaxy S10

Tags: 9.0-pie, android-auto, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I've a Samsung Galaxy S10e smartphone with Android Pie as OS. When I connect it using an USB cable to my car *(Audi A1)* and start Android Auto from the car display, it doesn't work.

I can't say what the problem is because I don't see any error message.

What's wrong with it? I'm using Android Auto from Belgium *(Europe)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem. To solve it I've installed the [Android Auto from APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-auto/android-auto-4-4-5923-release/) app on my smartphone. This I've done because Android Auto is not yet supported in my country *(Belgium)* and The Netherlands.